# Understanding the concept of SpriteKit Nodes

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

So I'm very new to SpriteKit and Swift, and I don't really understand the concept behind nodes (or really anything in sprite-kit for the matter). I'm requesting you explain the concept of nodes to me.

I'm much more used to having a different instance of a variable for each node (such as making an array), which allows me to very specifically reference any single node. However in sprite kit this doesn't seem to be the case since you simply just make it once and call multiple instances of it with addChild. (Way better than what I've been doing...)

This kinda boggles me because I mainly don't understand how I could test a scenario or something for these or reference one individually. For example, I'm trying to get an object to be removed from the scene with `removeFromParent()`, but I don't how to implement something like:

```
if(enemy.position.x == 0)
{
SKAction.removeFromParent()
}
```

Before I would setup a for loop that checks every single enemy but this is SUPER inefficient. I think I would do this in the update method provided by the physics engine, but like I said I have no idea how to call it.

So my question is basically to have you explain to me the concept of what's going on here. Pretend I have absolutely no knowledge of this type of programming (which I pretty much don't) and if you could break it down to me like I'm five that would be great :D!

Thanks!

Comment: SO is not a tutorial site, it is a site for specific questions and answers, if you want to learn about SpriteKit, I would suggest you look at a tutorial site like http://www.raywenderlich.com/

Comment: @KnightOfDragon - I could not disagree more.  SO is the perfect venue for questions of this nature.  There is a huge community of coders here who are willing to impart their knowledge.  SO needs to lighten up in a major way.

Comment: Essentially you don't have to keep track of every node (in an array etc) because when a node is involved in something interesting (a collision, it touches something, someone touches it with their finger etc) your code will be passed the node involved in the interesting event. For your  'enemy.position.x == 0' example, you can use enumerateChildNodeswithName to check the position of every node; or you could set up a boundary with collision detection and get notified when the enemy reached that position. Or you could subclass enemy, and get all the enemies to check their own position etc etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar troubles when first learning SpriteKit, coming from working with UI* objects.

**To get every node in a scene**

```
self.children
```

OR you can pass `//*` into [enumerateChildNodesWithName:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock:)

**To get a specific node** [you can reference it by name.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/childNodeWithName:)

```
self.childNodeWithName("myNode")
```

**To get a node at a touch location**

*Objective-C*

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKSpriteNode *touchedNode = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:positionInScene];
}
```

*Swift*

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = (touch as UITouch).locationInNode(self)
        if let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(location) {
            // Do something with node here.
        }
    }
}
```

I almost always give a name to my nodes as it makes them far easier to work with.
It's also the only way you can really interact with them when designing your scenes in .sks files.

What helped me was looking at the button implementation on Apples [DemoBots](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DemoBots/Introduction/Intro.html) sample project.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for mass quantities of nodes? For example I'm spawning an infinite number of enemies but need to check if they are hitting certain parts of the screen. Any suggestion for that?

Comment: If you know these locations, all you need to do is use something like this self.scene.nodesAtPoint(location)

Comment: The idea  is that when a sprite does hit 'Certain parts of the screen', your code gets notified of the contact and also which sprite was involved.